# React-table filter problem with formated column data

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-table

I have a `react-table` with filters. One column has formated data. I Want to add `filterMethod` to this column.
The problem is I can't add  `filterMethod` because typscript says that:
`Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'filterMethod' does not exist in type 'Column<OrgData | StatusOpt>'`

```
      const teamTableColumns: Column<OrgData & StatusOpt>[] = [

    {
      id: "status",
      accessor: "status" as keyof StatusOpt,
      disableGlobalFilter: true,
      Header: props => {
        return (
          <Th
            {...props.column.getHeaderProps()}
          >
            <span>
              Status
            </span>
          </Th>
        );
      },
      Cell: ({ row }: { row: Row<OrgData> }) => {
        return (
          <Span>
            {customTextForRow(row)} // format data 
          </Span>
        );
      },
      filterMethod: (filter: any, row: any) => {
        return row[filter.id] === filter.value;
      }
    },
];
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
 const teamTableColumns: Column<OrgData & StatusOpt & { filterMethod?: any }>[]
```